# Can I downgrade my iOS version to 7.x?

Tags: ios, upgrade, downgrade

Can I downgrade my iOS to 7.x? I need to do it for app testing.

Answer (score 0):

Due security reasons, there is no method to downgrade.

Comment: In the past I think there is. Is this a new thing by Apple?

Comment: You can downgrade from beta versions. But, with every new release of the system, apple stop signing previous releases, so those can't be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has full control what releases are available to install and downgrade. iOS 7 is not downgrade able unless you jailbreak your iPhone (not recommended!).

You can check if Apple still allows to roll-back your previous iOS version at [IPSW](https://ipsw.me/all) . Click on your device and see what versions are green (allowed by Apple) to install.